# Get users registered 30 days prior to date (inclusive)

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-5.7, mysql-8.0

I have a table `users`  that saves `user_id` and the timestamp `created_at` when user registers. I want to find number of registered users each day and number of registered users 30 days prior to each day.

To find the number of registered users per day i have:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(date(created_at),'%d %M %Y') AS Days, COUNT(user_id) as Profiles
FROM users
GROUP BY YEAR(created_at), MONTH(created_at), DAY(created_at);
```

To find the number of registered users in the last 30 days I have this:

```
SELECT current_date(),COUNT(user_id) 
FROM users 
WHERE created_at >=  NOW() - INTERVAL 30 DAY;
```

Now I need to do the same but instead of the `current_date()` or `now()` date i need to do it for all dates generated from first query.

I need it to work with mysql5+ and 8+.

Your help is appreciated!

Comment: Do you need the sum of every registration from now()-30, -29, -28 and so on ? So it will be like 3000, 2900, 2800.. if every day 100 user has been registered. Or you need the registration count for each day separately?

Comment: I need the sum (registered users) of the last 30 days by day

Comment: @Fenistil this is another example but I need to follow the same logic  https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Kwe7CFbUV6P3Byt4xQg23-DF1FLJS94mA7aYUQuuArY/edit#gid=0

Answer (score 1):

You can make a separate query which uses a window function to make the running sum, then join this data to the first query:

```
SELECT SUBSTR(created_at,1,10) AS "Dtm", COUNT(user_id), T1.SumCnt
FROM users 
LEFT JOIN 
(
    SELECT
        Dtm,
        Cnt,
        SUM(Cnt) OVER (ORDER BY Dtm) AS SumCnt
    FROM (
        SELECT
            SUBSTR(created_at, 1,10) AS "Dtm",
            COUNT(user_id) as "Cnt"
        FROM users
        WHERE users.created_at > NOW() - INTERVAL 30 DAY
        GROUP BY Dtm
            ) S1
) T1 ON (SUBSTR(users.created_at,1,10)=T1.Dtm)  
WHERE users.created_at > NOW() - INTERVAL 30 DAY
GROUP BY Dtm ORDER BY 1
```

Note: this needs MySQL 8+ to work.

Comment: I have MySQL 8.0.23 which is giving me the error 'grouping is not valid at this position' for the 
WITH grouping AS (SELECT...

Comment: I've edited it to use a sub select instead of with data. Try it now. (Btw I use MariaDB 10.5 and it works fine in it)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DISTINCT users.created_at, SUM(Profiles)
FROM users
JOIN (
    SELECT created_at, COUNT(user_id) as Profiles
    FROM users
    GROUP BY created_at
) counts
ON counts.created_at BETWEEN users.created_at - INTERVAL 30 DAY AND users.created_at
GROUP BY users.created_at;
```

Answer (score 0):

As you need it to work with mysql5+ and 8+ , window functions are clearly out of question . We have to capitalize on the features supported by mysql 5.x to reach the maximum compatibility. First of all, we need to calculate user_id count for each day in a subquery, which is used as the base table. Then we can use a correlated subquery in the SELECT list to get the 30 days' sum (each day and 29 days before it inclusively, which you can adjust) . Here is the code written and tested in workbench.

```
select ts as days,
    (select sum(ct) 
    from 
        (select count(user_id) ct, created_at ts from users group by created_at) tt 
    where ts between t.ts - interval 29 day and t.ts) as 30_day_sum
from 
    (select count(user_id) ct, created_at ts from users group by created_at) t
;
```